# Primary key exception upon unique property creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building an application with Asp.net core and EF Core. I am getting below exception upon execution with code first concept.

> 'System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData' requires a primary key to be
>   defined.

This only happens when I define `modelbuilder` with `isUnique` in my DBContext class. If I comment out entire `modelbuilder`, everything works fine. It creates database and tables with out any issues.

**Below is my** `Modelbuilder`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        // Make unique properties
        modelbuilder.Entity<Application>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<Domain>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<Roles>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<Environments>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<NetworkZone>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<Status>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<Type>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<OperatingSystems>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.OSVersion)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<Servers>()
            .HasIndex(s => s.ServerName)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<ResourceGroup>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
        modelbuilder.Entity<AccessType>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
            .IsUnique();
    }
```

Here is my `entity base` class that I am inheriting in all my Models.

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the created by.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The created by.
    /// </value>
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the create on.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The create on.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the modified by.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The modified by.
    /// </value>        
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the modified on.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The modified on.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by changing below model builder to correct Entity.

from:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Type>()
        .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
        .IsUnique();
```

to:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Types>()
        .HasIndex(a => a.Name)
        .IsUnique();
```

`Type` is used by System so there was a typo in my `modelbuilder`